# how to add more groups to mounts and files?

Tags: permissions, rhel, mount, ext4, gid

I was going to mount a windows share via mount.cifs and using dir_mode.

> mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt/ -o
> user=username,dom=domain,dir_mode=0755,uid=510,**gid=610**

This means only members of group id 610 will have access to it. But how can I add more groups?

In general I am asking myself how to set more groups to files in linux?

For example:

> drwxrwxr-x   3 Adrian HomeGroup1 Foldername

In this case only HomeGroup1 has rwx permissions. How to add more groups?

Comment: you can use `ACL`, please search for `setfacl` and `getfacl`. BTW, for example you have `group1` with users u10,u11,u12... and `group2` with users u20,u21,u22... you can simply create new group let's say `sharegroup` and add all those users to this group and the management will be easier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if these groups are coming from an active directory? I forgot to mention that this client is connected to a windows domain. Using bloody centrify software :)

Comment: `ACL` should work for AD users.